# Merging SPARQL query graphs in to one

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web

Imagine you have multiple Query graphs which may or may not share some some nodes (i.e. have some common sub-graphs) how could we combine them in to a single query graph. Please note that I am not trying to aggregate the result of those query graphs here I simply want to take few queries and combine them in to one query graph if possible.

Edit: I actually thought about this further, I am talking about multiple queries with common triple patterns. I want to combine them in to one query.

Edit: As pointed out, it would be easier with sample query to illustrate the point so let's consider the following queries:

Query1:

```
SELECT ?X   
WHERE
{
    ?X rdf:type ub:GraduateStudent .
    ?X ub:takesCourse http://www.Department0.University0.edu/GraduateCourse0
}
```

Query2:

```
SELECT ?X, ?Y, ?Z
WHERE
{
    ?X rdf:type ub:GraduateStudent .
    ?Y rdf:type ub:University .
    ?Z rdf:type ub:Department .
    ?X ub:memberOf ?Z .
    ?Z ub:subOrganizationOf ?Y .
    ?X ub:undergraduateDegreeFrom ?Y
}
```

The merged query would be written something like:

```
SELECT ?X, ?Y, ?Z
WHERE
{
    ?X rdf:type ub:GraduateStudent .
    optional {?Y rdf:type ub:University .}
    optional {?Z rdf:type ub:Department .}
    optional {?X ub:memberOf ?Z .}
    optional {?Z ub:subOrganizationOf ?Y .}
    optional {?X ub:undergraduateDegreeFrom ?Y} 
    optional { ?X ub:takesCourse http://www.Department0.University0.edu/GraduateCourse0}

}
```

Or maybe potentially re-written as a federated query? would that be possible using some kind of API?

Comment: What is a "query graph"? Are you talking about named graphs?  Are you asking about multiple graph patterns in a SPARQL query?

Comment: Based on you comment on Michael's answer, it sounds like the latter, but that's just a matter of concatenating them.  If you have pattern one: `<x> :likes ?person` and pattern two: `<x> :eats ?food`, you just merge them as: `<x> :likes ?person . <x> :eats ?food .`.  Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think the way I initially explained it was confusing, I am talking about multiple queries with common triple patterns and some triple patterns that might not be common among them. I want to create one query that represent them all.

Comment: Concatenation should still more or less work.  duplicate patterns in the query won't hurt anything.  Are you looking for a programmatic way to do this, or something else?

Comment: yes programmatic way would be great, one way I thought of was using Jenna to get the triple patterns for each query and if there are common triple patterns then you would combine them. I want the result set to be the same as running the queries separately. That mean you can't just combine to random queries.
Another question I have is that how use of filter clause in one query might affect this combining of queries.

Comment: How could the result sets be the same? If one query binds variables that the other doesn't, then there will be variables in one that weren't in the other.  Also, you didn't mention Jena in your question, so there was no reason for anyone to suppose that you wanted that kind of an answer.  This will be much clearer if you can show an example of two of the kinds of queries you're interested in, and what their merge/combination would be.  If you can show that, then we can probably show you how to do it programmatically with Jena.

Comment: Cross posted on answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26232/merging-sparql-query-graphs-in-to-one .

Comment: Voted to close since as others have pointed out we can't answer your question without more information

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're asking. If the question is literally "is this possible using some API" then the answer is "yes". Tools like Jena or Sesame provide you with the APIs and parsers/processors to do this kind of thing. You're unlikely to get a more specific answer unless get more specific though: what have you tried, for example?

Comment: I have tried using Jenna and yes I am aware of the fact that is possible to do so. What I am wondering is the following:
Does this (Merging queries like this), really makes sense?
Is it more efficient/less efficient? Obviously query and data factors in here as well.
can APIs such as jenna help convert this to a federated query as well (I haven't tried this yet)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the ability to [specify the active graph](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#specifyingDataset) the query is evaluated against.  Basically you use `FROM` and/or `FROM NAMED` to tell the query engine the graphs you'd like considered when evaluating your query.

Comment: I know what you are talking about but that is not what I  am looking for! From the theoretical perspective SPARQL query is a small graph pattern matched against the RDF graph. I have have several of these query graph how would it possible to merge them in to one query graph.  I am not trying specify which graph to query from.